# DataFormatter.date(from: " ") return wrong value (- 1 day) Swift

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I have problem with `DateFormatter`. I set my Current TimeZone `formatter.timezone = Calendar.current.timezone` but when I convert from current Date  `Date()` I get value with - 1 day

My Code

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
let date = Date()
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date) // "2018-04-24"
viewModel.currentDate = formatter.date(from: dateString)!
print("\(viewModel.currentDate)") // "2018-04-23"
```

I know this is bad timeZone, but how set my time zone for convert date from string, if convert date to string work good

Comment: The date is correct. Please be aware that `Date` instances are `print`ed always in UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let date = Date()
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date) // "2018-04-24"
print("\(formatter.string(from: formatter.date(from: dateString)!))") // "2018-04-23"
```

Comment: This is work but can I set dateFormat for this? My result: convert to string: 2018-04-24
and for convert to date : 2018-04-24 00:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

To set the `timeZone` property you need to provide a `NSTimeZone` instance. You can create one for instance:

• NSTimeZone(name: "Pacific Daylight Time")
 • NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")
 • NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 3600)

Remember to use a TimeZone name and not a city name.

Comment: I try this and "Cannot assign value of type 'NSTimeZone?' to type 'TimeZone!'"

Comment: You need to do: `if let timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "PST") {...`